# Store private data on external storage

Tags: android

I need that the files generated by my application don't be accessible by others applications. The problem is that these files are multimedia files (photos, videos, audios ...) and are too large to be stored in the internal memory. Encrypt is not an option because the cost of memory for display in galleries or play would be too high.

Any idea?

Comment: well, if cant encrypt then may be you can just change the extension or just encrypt the header of these files. dont know for sure btw

Comment: got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Anything stored on the external storage is potentially accessible by anyone. Unless you encrypt your data it will be readable.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you've had enough place to store it internally, anyone with rooted device would have access to your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your information on a secure server and use a secure connection.  It could be painful with any media, but especially video to retrieve and consume.  If you had any way to know what was going to be accessed, you could store that locally.  Not ideal, but more secure than changing the filename or leaving the content on the device/sdcard.